# WooCommerce Over HTTP Authentication Error on Android

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been working on integrating OAuthentication using HTTP on WooCommerce on Android and iOS.

When using the same Consumer Key "ck_xxxx" and Consumer Secret "cs_xxxx", I am able to generate the OAuth Signature using the HMAC-SHA1 siging method. The problem I am facing is that, on iOS I am able to list the products available using mysite.com/mystore/wp-json/wc/v1/products but, when I use the same thing on Android, I get a "Sorry, You cannot list resources" with a 401 status error.

I am not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong!!

What could be the reason for this type of an error?

**Wordpress version: 4.7
WooCommerce version: 2.6.11
WooCommerce Rest API Version: v1 (After Legacy)**

**Edit:**

On Android, It works when using the old Legacy WooCommerce v3 RESTful API